# How to add HttpClientHandler to url?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, flurl

I have this request handler:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Address, proxy.Port),
    UseProxy = true
};
```

And:

```
var url = new Url(hostUrl)
    .AppendPathSegment(pathSegment);
```

How do I add the request handler to the FlurlClient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own `ProxiedHttpClientFactory` that overrides the `CreateMessageHandler()` method:

```
public class ProxiedHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly string _proxyAddress;
    private readonly int _proxyPort;

    public ProxiedHttpClientFactory(string proxyAddress, int proxyPort)
    {
        this._proxyAddress = proxyAddress;
        this._proxyPort = proxyPort;
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(this._proxyAddress, this._proxyPort),
            UseProxy = true
        };
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var settings = new FlurlHttpSettings
{
    HttpClientFactory = new ProxiedHttpClientFactory("my.proxy.com", 8080)
};

var client = new FlurlClient(settings);
```

And on an existing `Url` instance:

```
var url = new Url(hostUrl)
               .AppendPathSegment(pathSegment)
               .ConfigureClient(settings => settings.HttpClientFactory = new ProxiedHttpClientFactory("my.proxy.com", 8080));
```